# Telefon app searches only by surname

Tags: phone-app, google-contacts, search

In the phone app of a xiaomi redmi note 12 pro the result is only filtered by Lastname. The First name is not used. Whe I search for `Do` the results only show John Doe but not Don S Davis. The contacts are stored in the Google account.

In the google contacts app the filter is working.

The phone app `com.google.android.dialer` is in version 123.0.605723773 is the problem.

I removed all data and the Cache from the app. Restarted the device. Removed and added the contacts. Updated to the recent Android version 14 UP1A.231005.007.

How to fix it?